# Resistor calculation complicated?

Tags: resistors

I've been working on a project which is turning my Raspberry Pi into a laptop, and have just run into a problem about an LED I will be powering off the Pi as a logo, as it requires more volts than the Raspberry Pi can give. I assume that this will be no problem and the light will just be dimmer than it would have been, although I don't know how this would affect the resistor I would use for it - would i just use the volts given by the Pi divided by the amps needed by the LED to get the resistor power, or would something change?

Comment: Let it be the toughest problem of your project.... What kind of LED is it so it requires "more volts" than RPI can give?

Comment: I'm still uncertain of which LED to use, although it's either 9-12V or 12V at 300mAh which I'd be powering off one of the 3.3V pins (the 5V pins are taken by a fan).

Comment: I will just assume for the sanity that you meant `300mA` rather than `300mAh`... But such a LED is a little Sun, you know. A typical indicator LED is 1.5V/20mA.

Comment: You need to give LEDs a good googling. Spend an hour or two on that, then come back. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode

Comment: Okay... I think the difference might be that mine isn't a pin one; it is more of a chip LED - might this make more sense?

Comment: And yes - I did mean 300Ma!

Comment: Or even mA... I'm useless with a keyboard...

Comment: @MPi the fact that it is surface mount rather than through hole is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** You can't power that thing off the Raspberry Pi power pins. Build a proper high power LED driver with a separate power supply.

The voltage from the Pi (even the 5V pins) will be far too low to get any reasonable light out of it - LEDs are diodes with a forward voltage which has an exponential relationship with current - if you drop the forward voltage by two thirds, the current is going to drop by several orders of magnitude, and hence the light output will too.

Back of the envelope calculation, if you run a 9V LED from a 3.3V supply, you'll have a current in the order of nanoamps (10<sup>-9</sup> Amps vs the required 10<sup>-1</sup> Amps). Essentially you 3W LED effectively becomes a 3nW LED.

If you try to use a boost converter to bring the voltage, you're going to increase the current requirements proportionally. So if you triple the voltage to 9.9V, you'll need roughly 1A from the Ras Pin to power it. The 3.3V regulator on the Pi is not designed to handle that kind of external load. Neither is the 5V power for that matter.

Comment: Seems like overkill for a logo, too. I am thinking another solution is to just use a different LED that puts out less light and requires less current at a lower voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that LEDs have a minimum voltage at which they turn on, and that's not much less than their normal operating voltage.  So if your 12V LED is actually several LEDs wired in series, it may not work at all on a voltage as low as 5V, let alone 3.3V.

Comment: So even if I managed to power the LED (or another one which is closer too the voltage I can give (which is now 5V)), how would this affect the mA that it requires?

Comment: If you want the same brightness from fewer volts, you'll need more milliamps.  power = volts x amps.